# Sensitive data on configuration managment

Tags: configuration

How can I prevent some sensitive data (e.g. password for the SMTP module) from getting into my repo as part of the Configuration Management system?

Answer (score 1):

From page 17 of the [Drupal PCI Compliance Guide](http://drupalpcicompliance.org/files/DrupalPCICompliance.pdf):

> **Removing credentials from settings.php.** One can include a `settings.local.php` file within `settings.php` to ensure that sensitive information is not distributed.

This is good advice and is what most people do.

If you have a lot of information you want to store securely, looking at the [Encrypt](https://www.drupal.org/project/encrypt) module or even a [Lockr](https://lockr.io/) integration might be advisable.

Comment: Not sure if this is a good solution for the `smtp` case, where that module stores the username and password for the SMTP server in the Configuration Management system.